# Parsing XML with PHP. Duplicate node names

Tags: php, xml

I am parsing xml file with simplexml_load_file() function. I have problem when i meet two nodes with same name. My XML file structure is:

```
<company>
    <name>Test Co</name>
    <link href="link1" rel="self"/>
    <link href="link2" rel="www"/>
</company>
```

And here is the code:

```
$parametrs = simplexml_load_file("my.xml");
foreach ($parametrs->company as $param ) {
    echo $param->name;    
}
```

How can i echo link2 from each company?

Comment: i want to get just link2 url.

Comment: Why do you want to take the second link? Is it really that wat you want or do you want to take the link with rel="www"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<company>
<name>Test Co</name>
<link href="link1" rel="self"/>
<link href="link2" rel="www"/>
</company>';


$parameters = new SimpleXmlElement($xml);

echo (string)$parameters->link[1]['href'];  // note you must cast here!
```

This will output 'link2' (without quotes around it).

Also, you may want to do some checking up front that these elements exist, but I'll leave that up to you as it's outside the scope of the question ;)

Comment: Note this solution depends on the order of the elements. I recommend you to use the xPath-way doing it! Specialy if you don't build the XML by yourself

Comment: Note that when you load an XML file into SimpleXML, the returned object represents the XML root node, `<company>` in this case.

Comment: @MarkusI. If the XML is this same simple structure every time, with nothing but a few nodes, I'd actually vote for the solution above.  I'm a big fan of XPath though, but find it more useful to get at a particular node deep within the tree.

Comment: I prefer the way with XPath, because he said, that this XML comes from an external ressource... I think he decided to take link2, becouse of the rel-attribute. If another Link will be added, you can get in trouble if you rely on the order...

Answer (score 0):

You can use xPath:

```
 <?php
$sxml = simplexml_load_string('<company>
<name>Test Co</name>
<link href="link1" rel="self"/>
<link href="link2" rel="www"/>
</company>');


$link = $sxml->xPath('//link[@rel="www"]');

var_dump($link);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/C4VU9q

Greetings

Comment: This is useless in this case because you need to know the value 'link2' ahead of time (which OP surely won't)...  If you were going to use xpath, you'd want to tell it to find the second 'link' node.

Answer (score 0):

When you load an XML file into SimpleXML, the returned object represents the XML root node, `<company>` in your case.

So, you just simply need to get the 2nd link tag, and get its `href`.

```
$parametrs = simplexml_load_file("my.xml");
// you need to case here, as this is actually a SimpleXML element, not a string
echo (string)$parametrs->link[1]['href'];
```

Comment: You really should get in the habit of casting to a (string) here IMO...  The echo will do that for you in this case sure, but if you're not aware that a cast is required, sometime later you'll assign a value instead of echo and wonder why it's not a string.

Comment: @quickshiftin: Ah yes, that's right, SimpleXML actually returns an SimpleXMLElement, not a string.  I'll add the cast.

Answer (score -1):

You can try my class It uses **simple xml**

Here's Code

```
<?php
  class xml_grabber
        {
            private $xml_file       = '' ;
            private $xml_link       = '' ;
            private $xml_dom        = '' ;
            private $xml_type       = '' ;
            private $xml_content    = '' ;
            private $xml_errors     = array() ;
            public  $xml_stack      = 0  ;
            public  $only_text      = 0 ;

            private $xml_connect_count  = 0 ;

            public function __construct($link_file_com = '')
                   {
                       if(!$link_file_com)
                            {
                              $this->xml_errors['construct'] = 'No Xml In Construct' ;
                              return false;
                            }
                       elseif(!function_exists('simplexml_load_file') || !function_exists('simplexml_load_string') || !function_exists('simplexml_import_dom'))
                            {
                              $this->xml_errors['functions'] = 'simple xml function not exists' ;
                              return false;
                            }
                       else
                            {
                             $this->set_xml(trim($link_file_com)) ;
                            }
                   }

             public function only_text( $val = 0 )
                  {
                    $this->only_text = $val ;
                  }

             public function set_xml($xml)
                   {
                      if(isset($xml{3}))
                        {
                           if(file_exists($xml))
                              {
                                $this->xml_type = 1 ;
                                $this->xml_file = $xml ;
                              }
                          elseif(filter_var($xml, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
                              {
                                $this->xml_type = 2 ;
                                $this->xml_link = $xml ;
                              }
                          else
                              {
                                $this->xml_type = 3 ;
                                $this->xml_dom  = $xml ;
                              }
                        }
                      else
                        {
                          $this->xml_type = '' ;
                        }
                   }

             public function get_xml()
                   {
                      if($this->xml_type == '')
                            {
                              return false ;
                            }
                      elseif($this->xml_type == 1)
                            {
                              return $this->xml_file ;
                            }
                      elseif($this->xml_type == 2)
                            {
                              return $this->xml_link ;
                            }
                      elseif($this->xml_type == 3)
                            {
                              return $this->xml_dom ;
                            }
                   }

             public function set_columns($new_columns= array())
                   {
                      return $this->xml_columns = $new_columns ;
                   }
             public function get_columns()
                   {
                     return $this->xml_columns ;
                   }

             public function load()
                   {
                     if($this->xml_type == '')
                            {
                              $this->xml_errors['loader'] = 'Unknown XML type' ;
                              return false;
                            }
                      elseif($this->xml_type == 1)
                            {
                              $xml = simplexml_load_file($this->xml_file,null, LIBXML_NOCDATA) ;
                              $this->xml_content = $xml ;
                            }
                      elseif($this->xml_type == 2)
                            {
                               $con = $this->connect($this->xml_link);
                               $this->xml_content = simplexml_load_string(trim($con),null, LIBXML_NOCDATA) ;
                            }
                      elseif($this->xml_type == 3)
                            {
                              return $this->xml_dom ;
                            }
                   }

             public function fetch($return = 'array')
                    {
                        $xml  = array() ;
                        if($this->xml_content)
                            {
                               print_r ( $this->get_attribute($this->xml_content)) ;
                            }
                    }

            public function get_attribute($object)
                    {
                       if( (is_array( $object ) || is_object( $object )) && count( $object ) > 0 )
                            {
                                  foreach( $object as $k => $val )
                                      {
                                          $count = count( $val ) ;

                                          $cou   = count( $object->$k ) ;

                                          if( $count > 0 and is_array( $val ) || is_object( $val ) )
                                              {
                                                if( $cou > 1 )
                                                     {
                                                       $result['item'][] = $this->get_attribute( $val ) ;
                                                     }
                                                else
                                                     {
                                                       $result[$k] = $this->get_attribute( $val ) ;
                                                     }
                                              }
                                          else
                                              {
                                                $attr = $val->attributes() ;

                                                if( count( $attr ) > 0 )
                                                      {
                                                        $var  ;
                                                        foreach( $attr as $kk => $vv )
                                                              {
                                                                $var[$kk] = (string) $vv ;
                                                              }
                                                        if( $cou > 1 )
                                                             {
                                                               $result[$k][] =  $var ;
                                                             }
                                                        else
                                                             {
                                                               $result[$k] =  $var ;
                                                             }
                                                      }
                                                else
                                                      {

                                                        $result[$k] =  (string) $val ;
                                                      }
                                              }
                                      }
                            }
                       else
                            {
                              $result[] =  $object ;
                            }

                       return $result ;
                    }

/*
             public function fetch($return = 'array')
                    {

                        if($this->xml_content)
                            {
                               $rss_feed = $this->xml_content ;
                               $rss_title = (string) $rss_feed->channel->title ;
                               $rss_link  = (string) $rss_feed->channel->link  ;
                               $rss_cat   = (string) $rss_feed->channel->category  ;
                               $rss_image = (string) $rss_feed->channel->image->url  ;

                               $rss_summary =
                                            array
                                            (
                                              'info' =>
                                                        array(
                                                                'title'=>$rss_title ,
                                                                'link'=>$rss_link ,
                                                                'cat'=>$rss_cat ,
                                                                'image'=>$rss_image
                                                                ) ,
                                              'item' =>  array()

                                            ) ;

                            if(is_array($rss_feed->channel) or is_object($rss_feed->channel))
                                {
                                      if(is_array($rss_feed->channel->item) or is_object($rss_feed->channel->item))
                                         {
                                             foreach($rss_feed->channel->item as $item)
                                                     {
                                                         if($item->enclosure && $item->enclosure->attributes())
                                                              {
                                                                  $image0 = $item->enclosure->attributes() ;
                                                                  $image_url = $image0 ['url'] ;
                                                              }

                                                         $result = array() ;
                                                         foreach($item as $k=>$v)
                                                                {
                                                                      $result[strtolower($k)] = strip_tags((string) $v) ;
                                                                }
                                                         if(isset($image_url{1}))
                                                            {
                                                              $result['image0'] = $image_url ;
                                                            }
                                                        $rss_summary['item'][] = $result ;
                                                     }
                                         }
                                      elseif(is_array($rss_feed->channel->entry) or is_object($rss_feed->channel->entry))
                                         {
                                             foreach($rss_feed->channel->entry as $item)
                                                     {
                                                         if($item->enclosure && $item->enclosure->attributes())
                                                              {
                                                                  $image0 = $item->enclosure->attributes() ;
                                                                  $image_url = $image0 ['url'] ;
                                                              }
                                                         $result = array() ;
                                                         foreach($item as $k=>$v)
                                                                {
                                                                      $result[strtolower($k)] = (string) $v ;
                                                                }
                                                         if(isset($image_url{1}))
                                                            {
                                                              $result['image0'] = $image_url ;
                                                            }
                                                        $rss_summary['item'][] = $result ;
                                                     }
                                         }
                              }
                            else
                              {
                                 if(is_array($rss_feed->item) or is_object($rss_feed->item))
                                         {
                                             foreach($rss_feed->item as $item)
                                                     {
                                                         if($item->enclosure && $item->enclosure->attributes())
                                                              {
                                                                  $image0 = $item->enclosure->attributes() ;
                                                                  $image_url = $image0 ['url'] ;
                                                              }
                                                         $result = array() ;
                                                         foreach($item as $k=>$v)
                                                                {
                                                                      $result[strtolower($k)] = (string) $v ;
                                                                }
                                                         if(isset($image_url{1}))
                                                            {
                                                              $result['image0'] = $image_url ;
                                                            }
                                                        $rss_summary['item'][] = $result ;
                                                     }
                                         }
                                      elseif(is_array($rss_feed->entry) or is_object($rss_feed->entry))
                                         {
                                             foreach($rss_feed->entry as $item)
                                                     {
                                                         if($item->enclosure && $item->enclosure->attributes())
                                                              {
                                                                  $image0 = $item->enclosure->attributes() ;
                                                                  $image_url = $image0 ['url'] ;
                                                              }
                                                         $result = array() ;
                                                         foreach($item as $k=>$v)
                                                                {
                                                                      $result[strtolower($k)] = (string) $v ;
                                                                }
                                                         if(isset($image_url{1}))
                                                            {
                                                              $result['image0'] = $image_url ;
                                                            }
                                                        $rss_summary['item'][] = $result ;
                                                     }
                                         }
                              }

                                if($return == 'json')
                                       {
                                         return json_encode($rss_summary) ;
                                       }
                                elseif($return == 'serialize')
                                       {
                                         return serialize($rss_summary) ;
                                       }
                                elseif($return == 'xml')
                                       {
                                         return xml_encode($rss_summary) ;
                                       }
                                else
                                       {
                                         return $rss_summary ;
                                       }

                            }
                        else
                            {
                              $this->xml_errors['fetch'] = 'No Xml Content' ;
                            }
                    }
*/

             protected function connect($link,$post='')
                    {
                      if(!filter_var($link, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
                              {
                                $this->xml_errors['connect'] = 'Not Vaild Link To Get data' ;
                                return false ;
                              }
                      if(function_exists('curl_init'))
                           {
                             $cu = curl_init();
                             curl_setopt($cu,CURLOPT_URL,$link);
                             curl_setopt($cu,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,true);

                             if($post != '')
                                {
                                    curl_setopt($cu,CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
                                    curl_setopt($cu,CURLOPT_POST,3);
                                    curl_setopt($cu,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
                                }

                                 curl_setopt($cu,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
                                 curl_setopt($cu,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
                                 curl_setopt($cu,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
                                 curl_setopt($cu,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

                             $co = curl_exec($cu) ;
                               if($co)
                                    {
                                        $con = $co ;
                                    }
                               else
                                    {
                                      $this->xml_errors['connect'] = 'No Result From Curl' ;
                                      $this->xml_errors['curl']  = curl_error($cu);
                                    }
                              curl_close($cu) ;
                           }

                    if(!$con and function_exists('ini_get'))
                        {

                             $url_fopen = ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ;

                             if($url_fopen == 0)
                                {
                                   if(function_exists('ini_set'))
                                        {
                                          ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1) ;
                                        }
                                   $check_fopen = 1 ;
                                }
                             else
                                {
                                   $check_fopen = 0 ;
                                }

                             if($check_fopen == 1)
                                {
                                  $url_fopen = ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ;
                                }

                             if($url_fopen == 1)
                                {

                                  if(function_exists('file_get_contents') and !$con)
                                   {
                                        $con = @file_get_contents($link) ;
                                        if($con)
                                            {
                                              $con ;
                                            }
                                       else
                                            {
                                              $this->xml_errors['connect'] = 'No Result From file_get_contents' ;
                                            }
                                   }

                              elseif(function_exists('readfile') and !$con)
                                   {
                                        $con = @readfile($link);
                                        if($con)
                                            {
                                              $con ;
                                            }
                                       else
                                            {
                                              $this->xml_errors['connect'] = 'No Result From readfile' ;
                                            }
                                   }

                              elseif(function_exists('file') and !$con)
                                   {
                                        $con = @file($link)  ;
                                        if($con)
                                            {
                                               $con ;
                                            }
                                       else
                                            {
                                              $this->xml_errors['connect'] = 'No Result From file' ;
                                            }
                                   }

                                }
                        }

                      if(!$con)
                           {
                             $this->xml_errors['connect'] = 'Curl And Allow Url Fopen Disabled On Server' ;
                             return false ;
                           }
                      elseif(stripos($con,'DDoS protection by CloudFlare') and $this->xml_connect_count < 1)
                           {

                                echo '<h2> Curl Answer No : '.$this->xml_connect_count.' </h2>'.$con.'<br />';
                                preg_match('/'.preg_quote('.val(').'(.*?)'.preg_quote(');').'/is', $con, $match);
                $matc = str_replace('+', " + ", $match[1]) ;
                $matc = str_replace('*', " * ", $matc) ;
                $post = eval ("return $matc ;") ;
                $html=new DOMDocument();
                $html->loadHTML($con) ;
                $xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
                $tags = $xpath->query('//input[@type="hidden"]');
                $fields = array();
                foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                  $fields[trim($tag->getAttribute('name'))] = trim($tag->getAttribute('value')) ;
                }
                $post_data = 'act=jschl&jschl_vc='.$fields['jschl_vc'].'&jschl_answer='.$post ;
                 echo '<h2> I will post this info to curl </h2>'.$post_data.'<br /> ' ;
                $this->xml_connect_count = $this->xml_connect_count + 1 ;
                sleep(5) ;
                $con = $this->connect($link , $post_data) ;
                echo '<h2> Curl Answer No : 1 </h2>'. $con.'<br />' ;
                preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: (.*?);/m', $con, $m);
                echo '<h2> Cookie from Result </h2>' ;var_dump(parse_url($m[1]));
                           }
                      else
                           {
                             return $con ;
                           }
                    }

             public function get_error()
                    {
                       return $this->xml_errors ;
                    }

        }

?>
```

Here's How to use it

```
<?php
    $rss = new xml_grabber('xml.xml') ;
         $rss -> load() ;
    $x = $rss -> fetch() ;

    print_r ( $x ) ;   
?>
```

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1256"?>
  <rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
           <info name="xml_reader" vesrion="1.0" author="sec.php"></info>
           <title> Xml By sec.php </title>
           <company>
              <name>Test Co</name>
              <link href="link1" rel="self"/>
              <link href="link2" rel="www"/>
           </company>
           <company>
              <name>Test Co</name>
              <link href="link1" rel="self"/>
              <link href="link2" rel="www"/>
           </company>
           <company>
              <name>Test Co</name>
              <link href="link1" rel="self"/>
              <link href="link2" rel="www"/>
           </company>
    </channel>
  </rss>
```

Result
Array
(
    [channel] => Array
        (
            [info] => Array
                (
                    [name] => xml_reader
                    [vesrion] => 1.0
                    [author] => sec.php
                )

```
        [title] =>  Xml By sec.php 
        [item] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Test Co
                        [link] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [href] => link1
                                        [rel] => self
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [href] => link2
                                        [rel] => www
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Test Co
                        [link] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [href] => link1
                                        [rel] => self
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [href] => link2
                                        [rel] => www
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Test Co
                        [link] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [href] => link1
                                        [rel] => self
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [href] => link2
                                        [rel] => www
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: This looks WAY over complicated for this problem.  What exactly does your class do?

Comment: It looks nice, but I don't think it'll really help here.  Plus the XML here is just XML, it's not RSS, nor does it have anything to do with RSS.

Comment: Thank you, i just check his problem with my class Because it way very useful for me , and i add my class to be sure of notification from stackoverflow users , this will help me too to develop good rss reader too :)